# How do mesoscale eddies in the ocean transport heat between different layers of the ocean?

Tags: ocean, eddies

And the atmosphere as well?

This is a follow-up question to https://www.quora.com/What-else-has-been-left-out-of-climatology/answer/Konstantin-Zahariev?&share=1

Comment: Please edit this question to clarify what the question is.

Comment: Voting to leave open, but it really could use some editing explaining exactly what the question is, and the context for it being asked (and linking to another site is not sufficient context)

Comment: Also, I think that this question would be more useful and easier to answer if it stuck to one domain - atmosphere or ocean. A separate question could be asked on the other, if necessary. Also, Quora sucks, it'd be better to contextualise the question some other way.

Comment: You asked (maybe unwittingly) a very deep and difficult question. At the very least, I think we need an idea of what your ocean/atmosphere science knowledge is (in addition to a more targeted question to answer).  In the meantime, check [this](http://paoc.mit.edu/labguide/circ_exp_fast.html) out! I wish I had more pictures of that setup, but you can kinda see how the eddies mix the warm and cold fluid.